# I get an error when trying to install strapi node v18

Tags: reactjs, strapi

[Image with ERROR!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps9c7.png)

When trying to install strapi with npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project

, an error appears. Everything used to work fine, now it doesn't want to install. In general, I can not solve the problem anywhere. Also tried reinstalling Python, node, sqlite3, gyp and nothing helped. Here is the error code ( it works with node v16 but i need 18 ;/ )

Answer (score 0):

I'm on macbook m1 with node 18.12.1. I can do this without any issue.

I'm not 100% sure what is the problem but the error messages are saying that when it was trying to install the "better-sqlite3". It couldn't find the prebuilt package (*warn install No prebuilt binaries found*) that fit your system so the installer tried to build the package by itself (`better-sqlite3@7.4.6 build-release`) but turns out still you can't meet the requirement it needed (*missing any Windows SDK*).

Try to install [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/) on your computer. I think I would fix the issue.

Comment: unfortunately, Windows SDK  not helped